# Which heroes get model upgrades at level 10?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In HOTS, there are a lot of variant skins for all the heroes, but most of them are static throughout the battle.  However [Dehaka regrows his arm](https://twitter.com/BlizzJohnzee/status/710156573067194368) at level 10, and Varian gains a shield, second sword, or just improves his 2-hander, to indicate which heroic talent he took.

Are there any other heroes that get model changes at level 10, either in general or just with specific skins?  Or are these two unique in that respect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Brightwing:** Gets colorful shadow effects if Blink Heal ultimate ability is chosen:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

---

**Cho'Gall:** Gets a hammer if Hammer of Twilight ultimate ability is chosen as Cho:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

---

**Dehaka:** As OP points out, regenerates an arm if any of ultimate abilities is chosen:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

---

**Gazlowe:** Gets disks if Robo-Goblin ultimate ability is chosen:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

---

**Varian:** As OP points out, wields different weaponry based on the ultimate ability chosen:

[image: Before]

[image: After Taunt][image: After Colossus Smash][image: After Twin Blades of Fury]

Some more info in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/heroesofthestorm/comments/4ne9zp/i_really_love_that_gazlowes_appearance_changes/).

Comment: This is a good start.  I do not know how but could you put more images side by side, like with Varian, to make the layout shorter?  One option is replacing both images with a single, side-by-side image.

Comment: Came from your post on MSE. Actually, the problem is you're trying to center an image with NBSP (or so it seems) which usually makes things more complicated. If you remove all the NBSPs, all of the images will be side-by-side naturally.

Comment: @Nae I don't know what do you mean by "look way better" except that it's centered on the desktop (and [the last one is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwomr.png)), and it's also broken on SE app.

Comment: @nae this is not centered at all on mobile and it looks pretty bad. (using mobile phone on full desktop site) - I know you are going for some sort of aesthetic choice here but it isn't working well, is it really needed?